# Run Native Client Within Chrome Frame in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-11, google-nativeclient, google-chrome-frame

Is there any way to run an existing pnacl app within chrome frame.
I tried to find a way to run it on IE but so far no luck.
Is there any way to run pnacl app within Internet Explorer ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Chrome Frame [was deprecated in 2013](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html), before the [PNaCl launch later that year](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/portable-native-client-pinnacle-of.html). Running the PNaCl VM is somewhat involved and doesn't make sense to support in a feature that was deprecated.